# I have this error in the console all of a sudden, what does it mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have encountered an error within Unity and I can't run my game because of it.

The error refers to a script within the Text Mesh Pro Package, and it highlights the Task type within it.

I've tried re-importing the package.

```
AssetFileRecord fileRecord = projectFilesToScan[i];
Task.Run(() =>
{
    ScanProjectFileAsync(fileRecord);

    m_ScanningCurrentFileName = fileRecord.assetFilePath;

    int completedScans = m_ScanningTotalFiles - Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_RemainingFilesToScan);

    m_ScanningCurrentFileIndex = completedScans;
    m_ProgressPercentage = (float)completedScans / m_ScanningTotalFiles;
});
```

This is the Error:

> "Library\PackageCache\com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1\Scripts\Editor\TMP_PackageUtilities.cs(310,17):
>   error CS0433: The type 'Task' exists in both 'Unity.Tasks,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'"

Comment: because somewhere this another class called tasks other than the unity one

Comment: Make sure to delete the entire `Library` folder and re-open the project in Unity. The `Library` folder is then re-build

Comment: so delete and reopen, and what do you mean by that last part?

Comment: library rebuilt still didn't work